# WinHTTP Request GET is not retrieving the response in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, get, winhttprequest

I have a macro which is triggering a GET call to the portal. Below is the URL structure:

https://{P_URL_PORT}/ibm/console/status?text=true&type=cluster&name={P_CELL}&time={tStamp}

Here is my macro.

```
Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", strURL, False, userNTID, userPassword
WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
WinHttpReq.Send
result1 = WinHttpReq.responseText
```

But I am not getting expected response. It is displaying the Login Screen response. I have tried adding POST method where it will send the Login URL, Username, and password. But still the GET call is not retrieving the actual response.

Comment: You're more than likely missing some headers.  At a minimum I would add `WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"`

Comment: I tried adding the request headers, but i am not getting the expected response.

Answer (score 1):

The open function for WinHttpRequest does not take username and password as parameters. If you are able to automatically login to the site in Internet Explorer then you may use those settings by SetAutoLogonPolicy()

> Caveat: Automatic login would imply not due to cookie but by the proxy settings. At times you can auto-login to a site because browser has remembered your last login.
>
> To be sure:- Close all browser windows. Open Private Window. If you auto-login now it means it is set in Internet Options and SetAutoLogonPolicy() should work.

```
Dim URL As String
    URL = "" 'provide URL
Dim HDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim whr As New WinHttpRequest
whr.Open "GET", URL, False
whr.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
whr.SetAutoLogonPolicy AutoLogonPolicy_Always
whr.Send
```

In case you need to login you supply the credentials, then use SetCredentials(). A good example of such request can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/refriedchicken/2885938)